# Python- get value of specific cell in Excel file using name of column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to get **value of cell** depend of `row_iterator` (which is just a iterated number) and name of column (in this case `'Organization CRD#'`)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json

row_iterator = 0
for file in os.listdir("./python_files"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join("./python_files", file)) 
        CRD_Array = df.iloc[:,1].values
        for single_CRD in CRD_Array:           
            with open("output/{}.json".format(single_CRD), 'w') as json_file:
                
                data = {}
                data['header']=[]
                data['header'].append({
                'Organization CRD#':  '{}'.format(df.iloc[row_iterator,1])}) // here I want to change '1' to name of column which is 'Organization CRD#'
                row_iterator = row_iterator + 1
                break
```

How u can see my script is

> 1. Reading files from python_files folder
> 2. Then it's reading second column with CRD number which returns an array of CRDs
> 3. Then it's looping CRD array
> 4. In that loop it's trying to get values from specific cells **and here I want to change number of column to it's name**

**How can I achieve that?**

Here also a little bit of **Excel file** for better understanding...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, os I figured it out.

Just need to and second tag to `.iloc`

After that, code with format looks like this...

```
.format(df.iloc[row_iterator]['Organization CRD#']
```

instead of chain indexing, include the column name in the index.

```
.format(df.loc[row_iterator,'Organization CRD#']
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way could be to use openpyxl library to manage the data.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Your file path here    
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'C:\Users\abc\Codes\FormulaFile.xlsx')

# Selects the default or first sheet
print(wb.active)

# Use this to select specific sheet
formulasheet = wb['My Form']

# Print the value of cell A1 of a specific sheet
print(formulasheet['A1'].value)
```